NPE while reading timestamp data type value for SAP SQL Anyware database
While reading timestamp column value from Sap SQL Anyware, getting NPE
Error log:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jooq_3.9.1.DEFAULT.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:739)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:948)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaDataFieldProvider.init(MetaDataFieldProvider.java:132)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaDataFieldProvider.<init>(MetaDataFieldProvider.java:83)
    at org.jooq.impl.SQLResultQuery.getFields(SQLResultQuery.java:99)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:285)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:349)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:368)

Debug images


In the above i used default dialect, if i use the sybase dialect also getting same issue.
Deatils:
jooq version: jooq pro 3.9.1 and jooq pro 3.17.3
database: SAP SQL Anyware 17
Jdbc driver: Jconnect4
Here i want to retrive the timestamp column from SQL Anyware17 database using jooq library.

This was also crossposted here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/17203

There seems to be a bug in how jconn4 interacts with SQL Anywhere 17. Just upgrade the JDBC driver to the one provided with SQL Anywhere 17, which is sajdbc4.jar located in the $anyhwere17dir/java directory.
As also discussed in this issue:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/17203
